# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Tags: python, float, pygame

Primeiro, assim que o mouse é clicado, guarda-se na lista bullets_array o ângulo do tiro ( que é o mesmo ângulo do player). Segundo, é dado velocidade ao tiro através do 'cos' e 'sin' e depois limita-se seu movimento para no máximo 640px e 480px pelo loop (assim, se ultrapassar o tiro será apagado). Terceiro, é mostrado na tela o tiro na posição do Jogador (player_x, player_y)

Era suposto que o tiro começasse no player_x, player_y, caminhasse em linha reta através do cosseno e seno e depois "morresse" nos limites da tela.

Mas é mostrado a seguinte sentença:

> line 53
>   vel_x = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
>   TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Aqui está o código:

```
#
# Title: Shoot The Zombies
# Author(s): John Redbeard, ("http://john-redbeard.tumblr.com/")
# 

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math

    # Initiate Pygame
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shoot the Zombies")
fps = 60
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Load images
player = pygame.image.load("images/player.png")
player_x = 100
player_y = 100
posplayer_x = 0
posplayer_y = 0

grass = pygame.image.load("images/grass.png")

bullet = pygame.image.load("images/bullet.png")
bullets_array = []

target = pygame.image.load("images/target.png")

    # Main Loop Game
while True:

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    screen.fill(False)

    # Load on screen the grass in isometric way
    for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1):
        for y in range(height/grass.get_height()+1):
            screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))

    # Load on screen the rotated-positioned-player
    mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y)
    player_rotate = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360+angle*57.29)
    player_position = (player_x - player_rotate.get_rect().width/2, player_y - player_rotate.get_rect().height/2)
    screen.blit(player_rotate, player_position)

    # load on screen the rotated-posioted-bullets
    for bullet in bullets_array:
        vel_x = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
        vel_y = math.sin(bullet[1])*10
        bullet[0] += vel_x
        bullet[1] += vel_y
        if bullet[0] >640 or bullet[1] > 480:
            bullets_array.remove(bullet)
        bullet1 = pygame.transform.rotate(bullet, 360+angle*57.29)
        screen.blit(bullet1, (player_x, player_y))

    # Load on screen the target
    screen.blit(target, (mouse_position))

    # Display window
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Run events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(False)

    # Event: W/A/S/D (Keyboard) moving player
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                posplayer_y -= 3
            elif event.key == K_a:
                posplayer_x -= 3
            elif event.key == K_s:
                posplayer_y += 3
            elif event.key == K_d:
                posplayer_x += 3

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_w:
                posplayer_y = 0
            elif event.key == K_a:
                posplayer_x = 0
            elif event.key == K_s:
                posplayer_y= 0
            elif event.key == K_d:
                posplayer_x = 0

    # Event: Mouse click shoot the bullet
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullets_array.append(math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y))

    player_x += posplayer_x
    player_y +=posplayer_y

    fpsclock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: Este problema foi resolvido? Alguma das respostas foi útil? Se sim, marque-a como aceita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linha com problema é essa:

```
bullets_array.append( math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y) )
```

Nela você está adicionando um único `float` ao array. Pelo resto do seu código, você provavelmente tinha a intenção de adicionar um `tuple` ao array, tipo:

```
bullets_array.append(
    (
        math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y), 
        math.atan2( nao_sei_que_calculo_voce_quer_aqui )
    )
)
```

Ou isso ou você continua a colocar floats no array e substitui `bullet[0]` e `bullet[1]` por simplesmente `bullet`. Eu não parei para entender a lógica e a trigonometria do seu algoritmo para dar a resposta correta.

Answer (score 0):

Quais os tipos de elementos de `bullet_array`? Essa linha:

```
bullets_array.append(math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y))
```

sugere que são simples números... O problema é que seu código que está dando erro:

```
for bullet in bullets_array:
    vel_x = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
```

parece esperar que `bullet` seja uma lista/tupla de números, e não um único número... Mas se esse array contém simples números, tal como adicionado pelo primeiro trecho citado, então ao tentar fazer:

```
bullet[0]
```

Ele reclama que não consegue indexar um `float` (já que floats não têm um método `getitem`).

Veja qual o tipo correto dos elementos de `bullets_array`, e assegure-se que todo o seu código seja consistente nesse quesito.